# why i get an error on slow connections in Socket io v4

Tags: javascript, socket.io

when i use socke.io at normal internet speed it works fine.But when I simulate a slow 3G in the chrome developer console.

This error is displayed:

> failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

How do I configure socket.io for slow internet connection?

This is my configuration:

```js
   io("ws:xxxxx.xxxx", {
        transports: ["websocket"],
        upgrade: true,
        path: "messenger",
        query: {
          token: "xxxxxxxxxx",
        },
        timeout: 1000,
    });
```

note: this configuration works on a fast connection.

Comment: increase the "timeout" value and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the socket before socketio has a chance to connect. Increase the timeout value to around 10000 (10 seconds), and that should solve your issue.

Comment: In my code I never use a function to close connection.

This doClose() function is called in websocket.js (this file is not mine) in the class: export class WS extends Transport of reactJS

Comment: I would try @Rajan 's suggestion and increase the timeout value, set it to around 10000.